# django migration creates table with only one field

Tags: python, mysql, django, database-migration

I'm trying to create a django app named 'store' , but when I execute `./manage.py makemigration store` then `./manage.py migrate store` the migration is applying correctly when viewing this table in phpmyadmin it has only one field.

my model code as follows:

```
from django.db import models

class Module(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Module"
        verbose_name_plural = "Modules"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='0.1')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500,default="No description")
```

and the result of `./manage.py sqlmigrate store` is :

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE `store_module` (`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

COMMIT;
```

I use django 1.7 on python 2.7 and mysql database.

Comment: Friend,It seems like fields declarations are not the part of your model.Check your identation.If it still doesn't works,Please attach screenshot of your model class from ide you are using....~Thanks

Comment: if you mean the indentation I fixed it manually while writing this question, thanks for notifying me.
or do you mean declaring them like:
`self.name = CharField()` 
?? please explain.

Comment: Looking here code seems absolutely fine.But still (Correct me if I m wrong)It seems like your fields are not part of model class.and that's why django is not puting them up in the migrations.It can be one of the reasons.But if still it isn't kindly attach the screenshot of your model class.

Comment: still don't understand your point of view any way I tried to write the model like this tutorial : [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#creating-models)
anyway I couldn't upload the image here because my points are not enough so I uploaded it on G+ [link](https://plus.google.com/u/0/102388781021090173865/posts/LNHLUynURU7?pid=6089421975032260466&oid=102388781021090173865)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after many trials, the problem is :

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'name' to module without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

so I added the default argument as empty string and 
solved.

Answer (score 0):

> name = models.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)

As I can see that this ***field is a model field and not a form field***.So, required=True won't work in this case.Instead use blank=false as specified in docs below.

[You should use this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/)

Hopefully this can be the potential issue.Please let me know for any other explanations in comments.

Comment: unfortunately, the same result. python itself allows the keywords arguments. beside this isn't interpreter issue.